# php incrementing time stamp error?

Tags: php, timestamp

I have a pagination function which pages through a time table and advances the dates on a weekly basis and displays the details relevant to the new dates.

Whilst testing some new data I encountered a paging problem. In that it would not page passed 22/10/2012.

Debugging the code I eventually found the source of the problem which is that incrementing the date stamp representing 22/10/2012 by 7 days returned (via strftime) a date of 28/10/2012 when obviously I was expecting a date of the 29/10/2012. This error effectively causing a continuous loop as %W (which drives the weekly pagination) is 43 for 22/10/2012 and 43 for 28/10/2012 and of course it should be 44 for 29/10/2012.

In a quick test to isolate and recreate this problem I used the following:

```
/*
 * test %W
 */

$time_Stamp_1 = mktime(0,0,0,10,22,2012);
echo "date : " . strftime("%d/%m/%Y", $time_Stamp_1);
echo "W for first time stamp " . $time_Stamp_1 . " is " . strftime("%W", $time_Stamp_1); 

$time_Stamp_1a = $time_Stamp_1 += (60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
echo "new date : " . strftime("%d/%m/%Y", $time_Stamp_1a);
echo "W for new date time stamp: " . strftime("%W", $time_Stamp_1a);

$time_Stamp_2 = mktime(0,0,0,10,29,2012);
echo "W for second time stamp: " . strftime("%W", $time_Stamp_2);
```

The pagination happily moves between all the other weeks I have tested and obviously uses this increment / decrement as appropriate.

Hopefully I am missing something obvious. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime) class is the way to go:-

```
$inFormat = 'd/m/Y h:i';
$outFormat = 'd/m/Y';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($inFormat, '22/10/2012 00:00');
$interval = new DateInterval('P7D');
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $date->add($interval);
    var_dump($date->format($outFormat) . " is in week " . $date->format('W'));week');
}
```

Gives the following output:-

```
string '29/10/2012 is in week 44' (length=24)
string '05/11/2012 is in week 45' (length=24)
string '12/11/2012 is in week 46' (length=24)
string '19/11/2012 is in week 47' (length=24)
string '26/11/2012 is in week 48' (length=24)
string '03/12/2012 is in week 49' (length=24)
string '10/12/2012 is in week 50' (length=24)
string '17/12/2012 is in week 51' (length=24)
string '24/12/2012 is in week 52' (length=24)
string '31/12/2012 is in week 01' (length=24)
```

Which, a quick glance at a calendar tells me, is correct.

See here for valid format strings http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php
Also see the [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/dateinterval) class.

See here for valid output formats for DateTime::format() http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: vascowhite Thanks please refer to comment on @Martin response above.

Comment: @codepuppy I'm not sure I get what you mean in your comment. What I do know however, is that the code you were using produces an error, whereas mine doesn't. I tested it over 100 iterations which takes it to 22/09/2014. See my modified answer.

Comment: There does not apear to be an equivilent of %W in the DateTime class. A test of strftime("%W",$date->getTimestamp()); works. I think substituting this in the strftime code may be the fastest way fwd.

Comment: @codepuppy %W is the week number, use '$date->format('W');' for that, see my edit. us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Ok thanks. I looked under DateTime::format and support date time formats on uk3.php.net/manual/class.datetime.php couldn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Or better yet use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime).

```
 // Create the DateTime object
 $date = new DateTime('2012-22-10');
 echo $date->format('d/m/Y');

 // Add one week
 $date->modify('+1 week');
 echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: Hi @martin this implies that incrementing the time stamp in seconds is error prone. I am assuming that you and the other respondents  are accepting that the increment in the code derived the wrong date! There is nothing in the php documentation that suggests mktime or the incrementing of a timestamp (however that time stamp is created - eg strtotime mktime time()) should be used with caution. Indeed such increments are demonstrated in the documentation. Are we saying that this fundamentally flawed?!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [strtotime()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for time calculations - e.g. to get the next week use:

```
$time_Stamp_1a = strtotime("+1 week", $time_Stamp_1);
```